# CPU getting hot. GPS can't lock on

Tags: gps, overheating

I know this was probably asked several times, but here's the deal: A couple of months ago I was charging the phone (Alcatel Onetouch Star) at my friends house, when I got a warning that the phone was getting too hot. After that, every time I use anything that's at least a little resource hungry (Facebook, note apps, video player, browsers, and obviously Youtube and games) the area below the battery gets warm, and almost burns my hand in some cases.

The battery itself doesn't get warm. The area below it, where the capacitive buttons are does. I'm guessing that's where the CPU is, and its getting hot. It didn't get hot before that night, it'd get only slightly warm when using YT or larger games (even in summer), but lately it's getting too hot, even though its winter and ambient temp is much lower than it was in summer.

Any ideas whats causing this? Oh, and also the phone can't get a GPS lock anymore. Not even after 5-10 mins under 7-12 satellites. I'm holding off on rooting it until I get everything sorted out, as I still have the warranty.